# regular expression limit hex number length by using OR

Tags: hex, expression

I want to limit the length of hex number to 4 OR 8. For example:

`0x0001` is valid (4 hex numbers)

`0x0001001F` is valid (8 hex numbers)

`0x00012` is invalid (5 hex numbers)

I can validate a hex number with length of n (n is 4 or 8) by using

```
Regex.IsMatch("0x0001", "^0x[0-9a-fA-F][{n}$");
```

How to achieve this OR operation, say either 4 or 8, not from 4 to 8?

Comment: It is not "number" but "hex digit" than you mean (e.g. `0x00012` is one single number written with four hex digits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Or" is represented by `|` in regex. Your regex would therefore look like

```
0x([0-9a-fA-F]{4}|[0-9a-fA-F]{8})
```

Another way would be to make the last four digits optional using `?`. This would lead to

```
0x[0-9a-fA-F]{4}([0-9a-fA-F]{4})?
```

Comment: You could make it shorter by matching the group of four digits 1-2 times: `0x([0-9a-fA-F]{4}){1,2}`